# Asyncstorage revives state for the wrong room

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am new to coding. Currently tryin to make a mobile app in react-native + firebase.

I am stuck at some really simple ( as i think ) stage, but spent a couple of days now but cannot find an answer.

In my app, user can create or enter room. Once created, room generates specific folder in firebase.

Creating and entering rooms work fine.

But whhen user enters a new room , he observes the state from the previous room even though it suppose to be blank as this is his first entry.

I dont understand how to solve this problem, absolutely crying now. A

Any help is appreciated.

This is a part of code where state is saved:

```
class  ChatRoom extends React.Component {
  constructor(zaza) {
    
    super(zaza);
    this.state = {
      allTasksComplete: false,
      task1: false,
      task2: false,
      task3: false,
      task4: false,
      task5: false,
      task6: false,
      task7: false,
      finishedTasks: null,
      zozo: false,
      newRoomName: '',
      creator: '',
    };
    

  }

  
  generateTask =  async (taskIndex, taskName,) => {

    const creatorCheck = await AsyncStorage.getItem('nickname')
    this.setState({creator: creatorCheck})
    
  const nicknameSnap = await collectionRef.where('roomName', '==', this.state.newRoomName).get()
   const nickCheck = nicknameSnap.docs[0].data()
   
   
    if(nickCheck.creator === this.state.creator) {

    firestore()
      .collection('Rooms')
      .doc(this.state.newRoomName)
      .collection('Alpha')
      .doc(taskIndex)
      .set({
        taskText: taskName,
        
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Task added')
      })
    }
  else {
    firestore()
      .collection('Rooms')
      .doc(this.state.newRoomName)
      .collection('Beta')
      .doc(taskIndex)
      .set({
        taskText: taskName,
        
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Task added')
      })
  } }


  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
    
    const trytextx = await AsyncStorage.getItem('currentRoom')
    const trial = JSON.parse(trytextx)

    const maybe1 = await AsyncStorage.getItem('task1')
    const string1 = JSON.parse(maybe1)

    const maybe2 = await AsyncStorage.getItem('task2')
    const string2 = JSON.parse(maybe2)

      this.setState({newRoomName: trial})

      if (string1 === false) {
      this.setState({task1: false})
    } else {
    this.setState({ task1: string1 }) 
    }

    if (string2 === false) {
      this.setState({task2: false})
    } else {
    this.setState({ task2: string2 }) 
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
      

    
    
    db.collection('Rooms')
      .doc('RRN')
      .collection('Alpha')
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        const tasks = []
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const data = doc.data()
          tasks.push(data)
        })
        this.setState({
          finishedTasks: tasks
        })

      })
  }



  taskOne() {
    if (this.state.task1) {
      return (
        <View>
          <TaskOne />
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            this.generateTask('Task1', 'First Task');
            this.buttonTaskTwo()
          }} raised='true' >
            <View style={styles.buttonDone2}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText2}>
                Выполнено
      </Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  taskTwo() {
    if (this.state.task2) {
      return (
        <View>
          <TaskTwo />
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            this.generateTask('Task2', 'Second Task');
            this.buttonTaskThree()
          }}>
            <View style={styles.buttonDone2}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText2}>
                Выполнено
      </Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
 
  CongratsMsg() {
    if (this.state.allTasksComplete) {
      return (
        <View>
          <CongratsMsg />
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.lastButton}>
            <View style={styles.buttonDone}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText2}>
                Получить
      </Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }






  lastMessage() {
    if (this.state.zozo) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.MessageBG}>
          <View >
            {
              this.state.finishedTasks.map(task => {
                return (
                  <View>
                    <Text style={styles.MessageText}>*** {task.taskText} ***</Text>

                  </View>
                )
              })
            }
          </View>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  lastButton = async () => {
    this.setState({ zozo: true })

}

  buttonTaskOne = async () => {
    this.setState({ task1: true })
    try {
      
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('task1', JSON.stringify(true))

     /* firestore()
      .collection('Rooms')
      .doc(this.state.newRoomName)
      .set({
        firstVisit: false
      }, { merge: true }) */
      
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

  buttonTaskTwo = async () => {
    this.setState({ task2: true })

    try {
      
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('task2', JSON.stringify(true))
        
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
    
  }
 
  buttonCongrats = () => {
    this.setState({ allTasksComplete: true })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground source={bgImage} style={styles.backgroundContainer}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.secondBg}>
          <DefaultMsg />

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.buttonTaskOne}>
            <View style={styles.buttonDone}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText2}>
                Начать!
      </Text>
            </View>


          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View>

            {this.taskOne()}

          </View>
          <View>

            {this.taskTwo()}

          </View>
       
          <View>

            {this.CongratsMsg()}

          </View>
          <View>

            {this.lastMessage()}

          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </ImageBackground>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: You should try to reproduce this behavior with simpler, more minimal code. It may help you find the problem yourself, and if not - it will help others help you...

Answer (score 0):

I end up saving my state in firebase instead of asyncstorage.